# Disable necessity hitting character when a suggestions lines count is larger than the window height in zsh-autosuggestions

Tags: zsh

[image: At Top: Hit TAB for more, or the character to insert]

When I start typing any command, for example `git` , plugin [zsh-autosuggest](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions) make suggestions that is working right. However, if my window is small, suggestions don't fit into the screen and "At Top: Hit TAB for more, or the character to insert" message appears.

I can't continue typing command until hitting character that is very annoying. How can I disable necessity to press any key and continue typing by default without activation suggestion menu?

Comment: `zsh-autosuggestions` does not produce any lists. It just show one inline suggestion. Do you perhaps mean `zsh-autocomplete`?